# neo4j path query with nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Env - Neo4j 4.0 enterprise
Plugins - GDS and apoc

I have a data in neo4j like below -

```
CREATE (a:hotel {hotel_id:'A'}),
  (b:hotel {hotel_id:'B'}),
  (c:hotel {hotel_id:'C'}),
  (d:hotel {hotel_id:'D'}),
  (e:hotel {hotel_id:'E'}),
  (f:hotel {hotel_id:'F'}),
  (g:hotel {hotel_id:'G'}),
  (h:hotel {hotel_id:'H'}),
  (i:hotel {hotel_id:'I'}),
  (a)-[:HAS]->(b),
  (b)-[:HAS]->(c),
  (c)-[:HAS]->(d),
  (d)-[:HAS]->(e),
  (e)-[:HAS]->(f),
  (f)-[:HAS]->(g),
  (g)-[:HAS]->(h),
  (h)-[:HAS]->(i),
  (ap:hotel_loc {loc_id:'pp1A'}),
  (bp:hotel_loc {loc_id:'pp1B'}),
  (cp:hotel_loc {loc_id:'pp1C'}),
  (dp:hotel_loc {loc_id:'pp1D'}),
  (ep:hotel_loc {loc_id:'pp1E'}),
  (fp:hotel_loc {loc_id:'pp1F'}),
  (gp:hotel_loc {loc_id:'pp1G'}),
  (hp:hotel_loc {loc_id:'pp1H'}),
  (ip:hotel_loc {loc_id:'pp1I'}),
  (a)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(ap),
  (b)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(bp),
  (c)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(cp),
  (d)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(dp),
  (e)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(ep),
  (f)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(fp),
  (g)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(gp),
  (h)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(hp),
  (i)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(ip);
```

2 scenerios 
1. List of the all node starting from
given a loc_id (example `pp1F`), i need to get all the nodes(hotel) and their associated :HAS_JUNC nodes.

```
f,pp1F
g,pp1G
h,pp1H
i,pp1I
```

2. List of all until the end.
   given a loc_id (example `pp1C`), i need to all the nodes until pp1C

```
a,pp1A
b,pp1B
c,pp1C
```

I tried this query, but no results -

```
MATCH s=  (h1:hotel)-[:HAS_PROPERTY]->(start:hotel_propert {property_id:"pp1A"}),
e=  (h2:hotel)-[:HAS_PROPERTY]->(end:hotel_propert {property_id:"pp1C"})
WITH h1, h2, s,e match p=(h1)-[:HAS*]->(h2) RETURN s,p,e
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What Cypher statements have you tried so far? What were the actual results versus the expected?

Comment: i tried this .. but no results

MATCH
 s=  (h1:hotel)-[:HAS_PROPERTY]->(start:hotel_propert {property_id:"pp1A"}),
 e=  (h2:hotel)-[:HAS_PROPERTY]->(end:hotel_propert {property_id:"pp1C"})
WITH h1, h2, s,e
match p=(h1)-[:HAS*]->(h2) 
RETURN s,p,e;

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the hotels that have a direct `HAS_JUNC` relationship to a specific `hotel_loc` (whose id is assumed to be in the `loc_id` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)) :

   ```
   MATCH (a:hotel)-[:HAS_JUNC]->(ap)
   WHERE ap.loc_id = $loc_id
   RETURN ap, COLLECT(a) AS directly_connected_hotels
   ```
2. To get *all* the hotels connected to a specific `hotel_loc`:

   ```
   MATCH (a:hotel)-[:HAS *0..]->()-[:HAS_JUNC]->(ap)
   WHERE ap.loc_id = $loc_id
   RETURN ap, COLLECT(a) AS connected_hotels
   ```

   In the [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern `[:HAS *0..]`, the `0` lower bound means that the pattern is allowed to match paths in which the `HAS` relationship does not exist.